# validation in import data from Excel file to database

Tags: c#, excel, ado.net

in my code I try to check if `dr[0]` contain alphanumerical and `dr[1]` contain alphabetical I try this code

```
                string pattern = @"([a-zA-z]+)";
                string pattern2 = @"(\w+)";
                MaamoonKhalidIssueEntities db = new MaamoonKhalidIssueEntities();
                foreach (DataTable table in result.Tables)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
                    {
                        string input = Convert.ToString(dr[0]);
                        Match match = Regex.Match(pattern2, input);

                        string input2 = Convert.ToString(dr[1]);
                        Match match2 = Regex.Match(pattern, input2);


                        if (match.Success && match2.Success)
                        {
                            Person addtable = new Person()
                            {

                                ncode = Convert.ToString(dr[0]),
                                nname = Convert.ToString(dr[1])

                            };
                            if (ValidateNewPerson(addtable, db))
                                db.People.Add(addtable);
                        }


                    }
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    excelreader.Close();
                    stream.Close();


                }
```

but in `if (match.Success && match2.Success)` it return false the code is not working

Comment: Check alphanumeric with - ^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$   Check characters only with ^[a-zA-Z]+$

Comment: the same issue and in alphanumeric I want to allow Arabic to in the code